# How to use an SVG as a responsive repeating webpage background?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to know how can use a dynamic SVG image as a webpage background with `background-repeat` CSS property.

Here is a codepen for the SVG itself: http://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/pyLkb

As you can see I have a hex that spawns another hex within it on hover with CSS transition. What I initially throught is that if I use the CSS `background-image:url('SVG.svg')`, that it would tile them up nicely and voila:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url('SVG_optimized.svg');
}
```

But apparently that breaks transition effect. I can technically tile this with PHP (or by hand, just by copypasting SVG objects), but that would make it very heavy on the client's hardware. Is there some way to tile this thing across the page without making PHP spam the page with 1000 and 1 SVG objects?

Edit: If I can't use the background tiling, maybe it's possible to add the hover animation directly into SVG itself? I mean technically it already is: the style of the SVG is imbedded into the SVG file inside `<style>` tag, but maybe there's some other way to use it such that it works with CSS backgrounds?

Like [here](http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html), the animation works on this page, despite using the CSS background method, except it's inside the SVG itself somehow. Maybe it's possible to have a mouseover event in SVG too? Inkscape has that property, but it didn't seem to work when I tried it (I put the CSS transition in there).

Comment: If I understand you then SVG background images don't work like that..certainly you can't apply transitions or hover effects. - **http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/**

Comment: Damn... Well is there any other way I can tile this across the page as a background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEkAy

here's a demonstration using javascript to tile the SVG in an absolutely positioned div behind your content (without having to repeat many instances of the svg in your html source.) I chose to use   `pointer-events: none;` on the content div to pass the events through (so the tiles highlight behind the page content). This means that if you want users to be able to select text or click stuff you'll need to either remove that line or add `pointer-events: auto;` to the specific tags you want mouse-interactable. Note that the entire width of the block `h1` element does not pass the mouse through, so the tiles don't highlight if you mouse over the `h1`. But it does go through the `p` element, and you can't drag to select the `p` element. (At least in Chrome!)

this also might not work on old IE. dunno!

```
full code linked at top. 
(snip)

var $svg = $('.hex').clone();
for(var i = 0; i<n_x*n_y; i++){
  $svg.clone(true).appendTo('#background');
}
$('.CLinner-path').each(function(){
  var self = this;
  $(this).on('mouseover', function(){
    self.classList.add('shiny')
    console.log('mouseover!', self);
  });

  $(this).on('mouseout', function(){
    self.classList.remove('shiny')
  });
});

(snip)

.CLinner-path{
  fill: #fa8928;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 6;
  marker-start: none;
  marker-mid:   none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.CLinner-path.shiny{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: With jQuery `.clone()`, ok. That's what I expected. It's JS so it puts strain on stuff like mobile devices. Even more so when you put `.onresize` in there to do the tiling loop on resize. It will also mean that each time resizing happens it's gonna be all messy for a split second or longer, depending on the hardware. If there really isn't a better solution for this, then I guess this is all we have right now. Thanks for the help! I'll wait a little bit to see if anyone has an SVG-specific solution, if not then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: All good points, sorry wish I had better suggestions for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create this (almost) fully in svg. See:
http://codepen.io/lemnis/pen/tCnGd

There are a few things you should keep mind:

- Instead of background-repeat, you have to use a svg pattern
- You can't use one pattern, because you want to animate a pattern
- SVG animation doesn't support a hover event, instead i'm using the mouseover and mouseout events to the trigger the animation.
- You can't use it as background-image because you will lose the interactivity

### For animating every element (edit)

Unfortunately you need some javascript for animating every object. You can see here a rough example: http://codepen.io/lemnis/pen/bxpEh. I didn't try to embed the svg with embed, object or iframe. But I assume it will work fine. Also I switched back to css hovers and transitions for a better effect.

Comment: This is almost what I need, but is there any way to do it so individual hexes are filled when I hover over them, instead of the entire page? Other than that this is pretty much what I need.

Comment: What you are doing there is what the answer before had: cloning the object. It can be done easier with jQuery.Clone method, no need to write the code yourself, as the previous poster showed. Unfortunately, it is quite spammy and will cause a lot of lag, as you can already see from the codepen. I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this effect using purely SVG methods or just without cloning, but I guess unless I spawn/delete a "fill" element inside each of the hexes on hover (which would be way overkill for such a simple effect), this idea is not viable.